# http / https / SSL

Tags: ssl, http, https

let's say I got a domain which is www.foobar.com
and if I try to visit my site using https://www.foobar.com

I got a message like "This Connection is Untrusted".

and I have created a name base virtual host for www.foobar.com
and only for port 80 and is that why i am getting Untrusted error or is there any thing I have to go.

BTW, I am very new to this topic so, any reference and explanation will be much much appreciated.. THZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a signed SSL certificate, purchased from a trusted CA. You typically buy these, although I believe there is at least one vendor for free certs. Google these terms; any professional IT person should be at least passingly-familiar with the concepts here. And you must have read the FAQ to know that this site is intended for IT professionals, right?